# How can i keep my image from enlarging the width of my page?

Tags: css, image, scale

When my website breaks at 800 pixels, my [photo on this page](http://jeffreydowellphotography.com/aboutjeffrey/) moves above the text which is correct, but it also scales up to the width of my site, which is bad. How can I make it stop scaling up. I want it to always be the same size, about 392 pixels wide. I tried the code below, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
img { max-width: 392px !important; height: auto!important;}
```

now its doing this, locking the footer to the bottom. Ugh.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Option A*

If you want it to always be the same size, change your css to this:

```
img {
    width: 392px;
}
```

Here's a fiddle with both your original code and my answer. http://jsfiddle.net/DrydenLong/Rs5F5/

**UPDATE**

*Option B*

Since you cannot edit the existing CSS, add the following code, but make sure it is loaded after the existing CSS.

```
img {
    max-width: 392px;
}
```

*Option C*

Or, if you have access to the HTML I would recommend using inline styles to do this. Something like below would also work.

```
<img src="..." style="max-width: 392px;">
```

Comment: I put that in, but it still scales up to the width of my site

Comment: @JeffDowell Strange, it doesn't scale on the Fiddle for me... What's the exact code you used?

Comment: its a template based site from squarespace, so im not sure

Comment: @JeffDowell No, your CSS code. Did you change it to what I posted, or did you just add what I posted to your existing code? The problem lies in the `max-width` property. Since you have it set to 100%, the image will always scale to 100% of the container, in this instance, the page itself. Try removing the `max-width` and `height` properties and only have what I posted. Unless you have done that already, then we may be dealing with other CSS in your template that is affecting the `<img>` tag.

Comment: @JeffDowell I see. You need to remove your existing code. Get rid of the `max-width` and `height` properties to make it function as expected.

Comment: i can only modify code i have added, not the original code. ill put all of my mobile code in my question.

Comment: I added    <img style="max-width: 392px;"> (didnt work). When I added your HTML (above) in the "code header injection" it placed a second image in the top left of the browser window

Comment: @JeffDowell to use the inline code from above you will need to replace your current HTML with it. If you can't do that, you will have to use Option B in my update.

Comment: I added       img {
    max-width: 392px !important;
   height: auto;
}

Comment: what i just added worked for the width, but now it stretches the height, how can i lock that?

Comment: @JeffDowell In the code you just added, change the `auto` in `height: auto` to whatever the height of your image is.

Comment: i updated my question, it fixed the image, but now the rest of the content doesnt stay up with the image.

Comment: Now you're dealing with either margin or display settings. That's probably better suited as another question since we solved the issue you had with the scaling of the image.